# Wort für »Sichtbarkeit der Beziehung von Sachverhalten«

Tags: word-choice, single-word-request, nominalization

Wie kann man in einem Wort formulieren, dass die Relation von Sachverhalten, die miteinander etwas zu tun haben, sichtbar ist?
Beziehungsklarheit? Verknüpftheitstransparenz? Bezogenheitssichtbarkeit?

Beispiel:

> Es gibt unterschiedliche Arten, wie die **Beziehungssichtbarkeit** erhöht werden kann. Zum einen kann in der Beschreibung verbal darauf hingewiesen werden.

Gibt es dafür etwas Schöneres?

Comment: Ohne etwas mehr Kontext ist die Frage nur sehr schwer zu beantworten. In welchem Zusammenhang soll der "schönere Begriff" verwendet werden? Wissenschaftlicher Artikel oder Roman?

Comment: Wissenschaftlicher Artikel. Beziehungssichtbarkeit ist mein aktueller Favorit aber so richtig gefällt mir das auch nicht.

Comment: Beispiel, bitte? Ein vollständiger Satz, der den Begriff verwendet, wäre schon hilfreich. Wir lachen auch nicht, wenn der Platzhalter seltsam klingt. Versprochen!

Comment: @KilianFoth ich habe die Frage um ein Beispiel ergänzt.

Comment: Auch wenn man es mit Sicherheit in einem Wort ausdrücken kann, befürchte ich, dass dieser Ausdruck nicht sehr schön ist. Für einen wissenschaftlichen Artikel halte ich "Transparenz" grundsätzlich schon mal nicht für verkehrt. Wörter, wie Bezogenheit und Verknüpftheit wirken gestelzt. Also wenn ein Wort, dann Beziehungstransparenz. Das jedoch klingt für mich spontan eher, als wenn innerhalb der Beziehung eine Transparenz besteht (Ich habe keine Geheimnisse vor meinem Partner).

Comment: Am ehesten würde ich spontan zu so etwas wie "Evidenz der Relation" tendieren, oder in mehr umgangssprachlichem Register "Offensichtlichkeit der Beziehung".

Comment: Ich würde auch sagen, dass "ein Wort" hier schwierig ist. Warum muss es ein Wort sein, warum kann es nicht "**Sichtbarkeit der Beziehung**" sein?

Comment: Es muss nicht ein Wort sein, wäre aber schön, da dieses Konzept zusammen mit anderen Konzepten in eine Liste kommen. Die anderen Konzepte bestehen auch nur aus einem Wort (Beispielnutzung, Lokalität, Abstraktionsgrad, ...). Es wäre besser, wenn auch dafür ein schönes Wort gefunden werden könnte, ist aber natürlich kein Muss.

Comment: Off-topic, aber was genau ist "Beispielnutzung"? Werden *vorhandene Beispiele* verwertet / ausgeschöpft oder werden *Beispiele entworfen*? Also mein Punkt ist, dass der Begriff auch nicht sehr präzise ist, und auch hier wahrscheinlich es sinnvoll wäre, in wenigen Worten dies zu umschreiben. "Verwendung von (existierenden) Beispielen", "Anwenden von Beispielen", "Einbringen von Beispielen" etc. — Die Einwortphilosophie ist oft wünschenswert, aber meist nicht zielführend.

Comment: In der Tat, ein guter Hinweis. Damit ist gemeint, wie Beispiele eingesetzt werden. Vielleicht sollte ich wie vorgeschlagen die Einwortphilosophie überdenken. 
Danke an alle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da es hier so oder so um ein Wort geht, das erst eingeführt werden müsste, wie wäre es mit einem schönen kurzen:

> Sichtbezug
>
> Es gibt unterschiedliche Arten, wie der Sichtbezug erhöht werden kann. Zum einen kann in der Beschreibung verbal darauf hingewiesen werden...

Nicht, dass das Wort in diesem Sinne schon eine Nutzgeschichte hätte, aber warum nicht zum Neuschöpf greifen dabei der Kürzegüte frönen?

Oder vielleicht

> Bezugspräsenz
>
> Es gibt unterschiedliche Arten, wie die Bezugspräsenz erhöht werden kann. Zum einen kann in der Beschreibung verbal darauf hingewiesen werden...

Nein? Na gut... dann eben nicht. Aber

> Relationsvisibilität

wäre ja wohl zu hölzern.